# Getting error:The entity or complex type cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have created a viewmodel:-

```
public class viewdata : Tool.Models.Administration.User
    {
        public string Categories { get; set; }
        public int RegionID { get; set; }
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
    }
```

It was first created inside Controller..Then i changed its location to Tool.Models.Derived.viewdata..Then am getting error inside Lists Actionresult in controller

```
public ActionResult Lists(int? page)
            {
                var ListIFC = (from f in _db.Users                          
                               where f.IsActive == 1 && f.UserType == 2
                               select new viewdata
                               {
                                   UserName=f.UserName,
                                   FirstName = f.FirstName,
                                   UserID=f.UserID
                               });
                List<Tool.Models.Derived.viewdata> obj = (List<Tool.Models.Derived.viewdata>)ListIFC.ToList();
                int pageSize = 3;
                int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

               return View(obj.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));     
            }
```

Am getting an error like this...

```
The entity or complex type 'Tool.Models.viewdata' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your statement:

```
select new viewdata
```

You are trying to project your query result to your class `viewdata` which is deriving from Entity framework. You **can't do that** in LINQ to entities projection. Instead you may create a temporary class and project to that or project to [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx).

Comment: if i create temporary class inside controller,is that accessible in business layer

Comment: @Mizbella, I think not, usually controllers have reference to business layer, so you can define the temporay class in Business layer and access it from the controller